# Prefill subform with data rows

Tags: joomla-4.x, form, subform

Im trying to prefill my subform with datarows from the database.

**newcustomerform.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form addfieldprefix="Mydestiny\Component\Mydestiny\Site\Field">
    <fieldset>
        <field name="id" type="text" readonly="true" class="readonly" default="0" description="JGLOBAL_FIELD_ID_DESC"/>

    <field name="contacts" type="subform"
               formsource="components/com_mydestiny/forms/contacts.xml"
               labelclass="control-label" multiple="true" buttons=" "
               layout="joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable-table" class="uk-table uk-table-middle"
        />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**contacts.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <form>
       <fieldset>
           <field name="account" type="radio" default="0" label="" description="" class="btn-group btn-group-yesno">
              <option value="1">ja</option>
            <option value="0">Nee</option>

        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I tried this:

```
$form       = Form::getInstance('com_mydestiny.newcustomerform', 'contacts', array('control' => 'jform'));
$input      = Factory::getApplication()->input;
$formValues = $input->getArray(array(
    'jform' => array(
        'contacts' => 'array'
    )
));

$prefillData = array("contacts" => array("account" => 1));
$form->bind($prefillData);
```

But that doesn't do anything.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the subform data one array deeper. This is because your subform has `multiple` attribute which means the data should be represented by multiple rows:

```
$prefillData = array("contacts" => array(array("account" => 1)));
```

This should work fine for your case. When reading existing data, be aware that the array keys are built using subform field name suffixed with a numeric index suffix, so the data is stored like this:

```
array(
    "contacts" => array(
        'contacts0' => array("account" => 1),
        'contacts1' => array("account" => 1),
        // More rows
    )
);
```